# Attaching property from another key in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database defined as follow [image]

I can retrieve the `cafeList` as follow:

```
 ApiManager.getInstance().mainDB.child(CafeModel.DATASET_NAME)
                .orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText)
                .endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
```

However I am not sure how can I attach the fact that particular cafe is also set as favorite by my user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve this in Firebase using only a single query. So in your case, you should query your database twice, once to get the cafe list and second to check if one of those cafe objects is favorite or not. However, there is a workaround in which you can create a new section in your user object named `favoriteCafe` in which you can add all user favorite cafes but this implies duplicating data. This practice is called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, i recomand you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). So in this case, if you want to know user favorite cafes, you can use a single query and attach a listener on this new created location.

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

Comment: Hi Muhammad! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?